# How to disable a particular list of dates in Datetime picker in ionic 2?

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I am working on application related to booking appointments.I need to disable the previously selected dates in dateTime picker.... can anyone help me....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `<ion-datetime>` then you should use them in ion-item (ion-list).

Comment: @parvathiG please vote for my answear click on the left (number 0) and the valid green cross if my answear was helpfull to you